# ASP.NET issues finding the id of a row after cheking if a value on 2 columns of the same table match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, model, controller

I want to get the `datacorrespondeID` if the value on `MesObjetivo` column is the same on `currentMonth`, and the value on `AnoObjetivo` column is the same on `currentYear` (the columns are on the same table `Objetivoes`). I want this so I can follow to a `If` statement according to if `datacorrespondeId` finds an id or not.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
var datacorrespondeId = bd.Objetivoes.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MesObjetivo == int.Parse(currentMonth) || m.AnoObjetivo == int.Parse(currentYear));

using (Volta12BaseDEntities bd = new Volta12BaseDEntities())
{
    if (datacorrespondeId != null)
    {
        string valorobjetivo = bd.Objetivoes.Where(m => datacorrespondeId.Equals(m.ValorObjetivo)).ToString();
        var Objetivo = new List<Objetivo>()
        {
            new Objetivo{ValorObjetivo = int.Parse(valorobjetivo), MesObjetivo = int.Parse(currentMonth), AnoObjetivo = int.Parse(currentYear)},
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: why are you using 'bd.objectivoes.firstordefault()' above 'bd = new Volta12BaseDEntities()'

Comment: Yhea my bad, but that doesn't seems to be the problem for not getting the value I guess

Comment: In your `datacorrespondeId = bo.objectivos.firstordefault(...)` what are the values of `MesObjetivo` and `AnoObjetivo` that you're comparing to? Theres nothing wrong with the Linq query from what I see. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for?

Comment: MesObjetivo has 6 of type int, and AnoObjetivo has 2022 of type int, datacorresponeID should be returning something but not null, since the values match, but is saves null value

Comment: What's inside of Objetivoes? Because nothing is wrong with the linq

Comment: @Train I just found what what was wrong:
            int intcurrentMonth = int.Parse(currentMonth);
            int intcurrentYear = int.Parse(currentYear);
            
            using (Volta12BaseDEntities bd = new Volta12BaseDEntities())
            {
                var datacorresponde = bd.Objetivoes.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MesObjetivo == intcurrentMonth && m.AnoObjetivo == intcurrentYear);
  I had to change the `| |` to `&&` and then convert to int before the linq